# Why is the terminal in an infinite loop with the prompts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander, inquirerjs

In relation to my previous question:
[Why is Node.js throwing an error to my require() statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77656833/why-is-node-js-throwing-an-error-to-my-require-statement?noredirect=1#comment136906452_77656833)

I added `type: module` to my packages.json and the code works and asks the questions. However, it keep asking the questions instead of stopping at the last question and replacing the placeholders.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import { program } from 'commander';
import { execa } from 'execa';
import inquirer from 'inquirer';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

program
  .command('make-plugin <folder-name>')
  .description('Clone repo and change values')
  .action(async (folderName) => {
    const repoURL = 'https://github.com/wpdev95/plugin-boiler/tree/main';
    const targetFolder = path.resolve(process.cwd(), folderName);

    // Clone the repository
    await execa('git', ['clone', repoURL, folderName]);

    // Enumerate through files and replace placeholders
    const files = fs.readdirSync(targetFolder);
    const questions = [
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'Test Plugin',
    message: 'What is the Name of your plugin?',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'test-plugin',
    message: 'What is the slug of your plugin?',
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'Plugin Author',
    message: 'What is the author\'s name?',
  },
];

    for (const file of files) {
      const filePath = path.join(targetFolder, file);
      let content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');

      // Replace placeholders in the content
      const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
      for (const key in answers) {
        const placeholder = `{{${key}}}`;
        const replacement = answers[key];
        content = content.replace(new RegExp(placeholder, 'g'), replacement);
      }

      // Update PHP file name
      if (file === 'plugin-boilerplate.php') {
        const newPhpFileName = `${answers['plugin_slug']}.php`;
        const newPhpFilePath = path.join(targetFolder, newPhpFileName);
        fs.renameSync(filePath, newPhpFilePath);
      }

      // Write back to the file
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, content, 'utf-8');
    }

    console.log('Plugin boilerplate was made successfully! Happy coding! :D');
  });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Comment: Please include a value for `questions` that lets us reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the code to include the questions and  proper repository.

Comment: Is the `execa` part even relevant to the problem? Does it still keep asking questions forever if you remove that part?

Comment: The `execa` part is supposed to clone the github repository to set up a new plugin project. @Bergi

Comment: Yes. But what does that have to do with "*it keep asking the questions instead of stopping at the last question*"? Try to keep your questions minimal.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I have to add `const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);` outside the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256281/discussion-between-wpdev11-and-bergi).